# why imagecreatefromstring() works on development but not on production server?

Tags: php, nginx

I get the following error on production server

```
imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format
```

But the same code works fine on my development server ( an ubuntu server with nginx 1.8 ). I am assuming this maybe a server config issue, I am running  `nginx 1.8`  and i have  `GD Support   enabled`  in  `phpinfo()` . What am I missing?

Here is the piece of code that generates the error

```
$ch = curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($raw); // works on dev but not prod
```

Please feel free to ask for any configurations and I will update the question.

Comment: Did you check that curl returned successfully?  If so, what's the first few bytes of `$raw`?

Comment: looks like curl returns 404! I am checking why!

Comment: If I had to take a stab, I'd say that production has different firewall rules.

Comment: I can't explain but curl was returning 404. Once I fixed that, I was able to use imagecreatefromstring() . You pointed me to the right direction :)